# Getting SQL agent in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, agent

I am coming from a SQL server 2008 background.  I have a mysql local server running, and I wanted to set up some scheduled jobs via the sql agent.  I have found some sketchy third party sql agents for mysql but none built in.  Is there a sql agent or a recommended one for mysql?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usual approach is to set up a cron job to run a script. I used to use Perl for the scripts, but bash etc will do it as well.